# Toggle-ing buttons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to change a button on click from Suspend to Un-Suspend and opposite. It works on changing it from Suspend to Un-suspend but without page refresh it won't change it back to suspend in live motion. I need to make it somehow in a toggle. I need it to be in 2 ajax because it does 2 complete different things. This is what I tried.

PHP/HTML

```
<?php
while ($datas = $data->fetch_object()) { // here I load the table
    if($datas->active == 1) { // I compare the value from column id
        $susspend_button = '<button id="susspendb-'.$datas->id.'" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm susspend">Susspend</button>';
    } else {
        $susspend_button = '<button id="unsusspendb-'.$datas->id.'" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm un-susspend">Un-Susspend</button>';
    }
?>
    <div id="susspendd<?php echo $datas->id; ?>" class="col-md-4">
        <?php echo $susspend_button; ?>
    </div>
<?php
 } // closing the while
 ?>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.susspend').click(function(event) {
    var id = event.target.id;
    var user = id.split('-');
    var user_id = user[1];
    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/ajax.php',
        data: {
            action: 'susspend_user',
            user_id: user_id
        },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#suspendb'+user_id).fadeOut();
            $('#susspendd'+user_id).html('<button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm un-susspend" id="un-susspendb' + user_id + '">Un-Susspend</button>').fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
$('.un-susspend').click(function(event) {
    var id = event.target.id;
    var user = id.split('-');
    var user_id = user[1];
    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/ajax.php',
        data: {
            action: 'unsusspend_user',
            user_id: user_id
        },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#suspendb'+user_id).fadeOut();
            $('#susspendd'+user_id).html('<button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm susspend" id="unsusspendb' + user_id + '">Susspend</button>').fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: initaalu based on the if loop the button load iether suspend or unsuspend, but when you click on the suspend button, the corresponding ajax should run and then change the button to unsuspend. Is that you want ?

Comment: do you have any error in console.

Comment: @loganSarav No Errors, It does like this: I click suspend->actions the ajax-> changes to Un-Susspend. Clicking un-susspend -> nothing, no errors no action, no change back.

Comment: try click function function `on` like `$('.un-susspend').on('click',function(event) {` apply this for both the buttons

Comment: Same thing, stopping.. no errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58049/discussion-between-logan-sarav-and-user3467855).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you click on the button, click function is not working, try addind a class to the `div` where the button is added like

```
<div id="susspendd<?php echo $datas->id; ?>" class="col-md-4 sample">
    <?php echo $susspend_button; ?>
</div>
```

and change the button click function like

```
$('.sample').on('click', '.susspend', function(event) {
```

and apply it for the both the button click function.

Answer (score 1):

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Praveen16oct90/Lt5Ej/3/)

I have done one example as per your code given... now tell me wat u want from this... Do u want the div u have created need to be clicked...

```
$('.susspend').click(function(event) {
    var id = event.target.id;
    var user = id.split('-');
    var user_id = user[1];
    console.log(user_id)

            $('#susspendb-'+user_id).fadeOut();
            $('#susspendd'+user_id).html('<button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm un-susspend" id="un-susspendb' + user_id + '">Un-Susspend</button>').fadeIn();

});
$('.un-susspend').click(function(event) {
    var id = event.target.id;
    var user = id.split('-');
    var user_id = user[1];

            $('#unsusspendb-'+user_id).fadeOut();
            $('#susspendd'+user_id).html('<button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm susspend" id="unsusspendb' + user_id + '">Susspend</button>').fadeIn();

});
```

Comment: not working, doing same thing. Working when clicking suspend -> doing the ajax -> transforming in un-suspend, but on reverse is doing nothing.

Comment: Found my answer,  logan Sarav helped me, he will post the answer in some mins. Thanks anyway for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple display none? and display block? hiding the button is the easiest way to go around it I would say :)

Comment: I am doing this with fadeIn and fadeOut.